# What is the probability of sharing a birthday if a year has an infinite number of days?

Tags: probability, limits, birthday

Here is the problem:

> Suppose that there are $k$ people. Each of them independently picks a uniformly random number from the set $\{1, 2,...,n\}$. We say that a collision happens if there exist two people picking the same number. Let $k = \lceil n^\beta\rceil$, where $\beta$ is  some  constant  that  does  not  change  with $n$. Prove that there is a constant $\beta_0\in(0,1)$ such that if $\beta>\beta_0$, then a collision happens with probability $1$ when $n\to\infty$; and if $\beta<\beta_0$, then a collision happens with probability $0$ when $n\to\infty$. Also find the value of $\beta_0$.

Here is my attempt:

The sample space is $\Omega=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}^k$. Let $A$ be the event that a collision happens. Then,

$$
    \begin{align}
    \mathbf P(A)&=1-\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-k+1)}{n^k}\\
    &=1-\frac{n-1}n\frac{n-2}n\ldots\frac{n-k+1}n\\
    &=1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\ldots\left(1-\frac{k-1}n\right)\\
    &=1-\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac in\right)\\
    &\ge1-\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}e^{-\frac in}\\
    &=1-e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac in}\\
    &=1-e^{-\frac{k(k-1)}{2n}}\\
    &=1-e^{-\frac{k^2}{2n}}e^{\frac k{2n}}
    \end{align}
$$

We used the inequality $1-x\le e^{-x}$. Thus, we have obtained a lower bound of $\mathbf P(A)$. Let $k=n^\beta$. Then, $\mathbf P(A)\ge1-e^{-\frac{n^{2\beta}}{2n}}e^{\frac {n^\beta}{2n}}$. For any $\beta\in(0,1)$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^\frac {n^\beta}{2n}=1$. If $\beta>\frac12$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-\frac{n^{2\beta}}{2n}}=0$, so the lower bound goes to $1$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbf P(A)=1$. If $\beta<\frac12$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-\frac{n^{2\beta}}{2n}}=1$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbf P(A)\ge0$.

I guess that I have to find a upper bound for the probability which goes to zero if $\beta<\frac12$, but I have been unable to find it. Here are my questions:

1. Does such an upper bound exist? If yes, how can I find it?
2. For simplicity, I used $k=n^\beta$, which is not valid because $k$ must be a positive integer. What happens if I use $k=\lceil n^\beta\rceil$?
3. When taking the limit, do we have to rely on the continuity property of probabilities? We cannot define a sequence of events $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ on the same probability space (although we could if it were $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_k$).

Answer (score 1):

An upper bound can be obtained using the inequality $1-x\geq 4^{-x}$ for $x\in[0,1/2]$ (an easy way to see this holds is that $4^{-x}$ is convex and equality holds for $x=0, 1/2$). The relevant part of the computation then looks like

$$
    \begin{align}
    \mathbf P(A)&\le1-\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}4^{-\frac in}\\
    &=1-4^{-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac in}\\
    &=1-4^{-\frac{k(k-1)}{2n}}\\
    &=1-4^{-\frac{k^2}{2n}}4^{\frac k{2n}}.
    \end{align}
$$
The upper bound goes to 0 if $\beta<1/2$.

For the upper and lower bounds to give the desired conclusion, all we need is that as $n\to\infty$, we have $\frac{k^2}{2n}\to 0$ if $\beta<1/2$ and $\frac{k^2}{2n}\to \infty$ if $\beta>1/2$. These limits still hold for $k=\lceil n^{\beta}\rceil$.

Comment: The inequality holds only when we are considering $\beta<\frac12$, right? Every element of the sequence $\frac1n,\frac2n,\ldots,\frac{k-1}n$ needs to be less than or equal to $\frac12$, and I found that the largest element $\frac{k-1}n=\frac{n^\beta-1}{n}$ is bounded above by $\beta(1-\beta)^{\frac1\beta-1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\beta\in(0,1)$.

Comment: For every $\beta\in(0,1)$, the inequality is true once $n$ is sufficiently large. If $k=\lceil n^\beta\rceil$, then $(k-1)/n \leq n^\beta/n = 1/n^{1-\beta}$, which is less than $1/2$ if $n > 2^{1/(1-\beta)}$.